# passing class members to void*

Tags: c++, void-pointers

```
class testClass
{
public:
    void set(int monthValue, int dayValue);
    int getMonth( );
    int getDay( );
private:
    int month;
    int day;
};
```

I have a simple class as can be seen above. I try to pass its objects to a function that checks whether they are equal or not.

```
testClass obj[3];
obj[0].set(1,1);
obj[1].set(2,1);
obj[2].set(1,1);
```

Firstly, I tried like `cout << (obj[0] == obj[1]);` but it is not possible without operator overloading, using template etc. So, I can do it using them but how can I pass the member variables to the `void*` function?

```
bool cmp_testClass(void const *e1, void const *e2)
{
    testClass* foo = (testClass *) e1;
    testClass* foo2 = (testClass *) e2;
    return foo - foo2; // if zero return false, otherwise true
}
```

I thought like that but I can't solve the issue.  I want to compare like

```
obj[0].getDay() == obj[1].getDay();
obj[0].getMonth() == obj[1].getMonth();
```

by passing.

Comment: What's the issue exactly? I don't get it from your question.

Comment: There is absolutely no need for `void *` here. Your `compare_class` could take `const DayOfYear &`, but you would either need to use public getters or make the function a `friend`.

Comment: If you don't want to compare by `foo-foo2`, then do something else. I'm extremely suspicious of the presumption that whatever you're trying to do should be done in a way that requires void pointers.

Comment: And you are missing some `()` on your function calls -> `obj[0].getDay() == obj[1].getDay();`

Comment: You don't need templates to do operator overloading. Your `compare_class` function is a very poor solution to a very basic problem. Why are you passing `void*` arguments if you just immediately cast them to `DayOfYear*`?

Comment: it is not just for class it can be also int and char arrays like compare_int, compare_char it works for different implementations but for class I stuck @LightnessRacesinOrbit

Comment: Why do you think you need `void*` for this? That came out of nowhere.

Comment: This is a very bad idea. Removes type checking ability from the compiler and thus removes it's possiblity to identify bugs

Comment: @itsnotmyrealname if you pass anyting else to `compare_class`, you are going to have some nasty results. Avoid `void *` in C++.

Comment: You are totally off track. Never (!) use type elision (void*), unless you have to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the compare_class function, that you have written, you are comparing the addresses of the actual objects. Which doesn't mean anything in terms of object equality. What should the function return? If the objects are equal? It is written in a way that states: if the locations of objects differ - return true; if locations are the same - return false, which is polar opposite from what you want.

Since You aren't using any pointers within your class, and don't want to use operator overloading, check out [memcmp](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/memcmp/%20%22memcmp). The usage would be as follows:

```
if (0 == memcmp (&obj[0], &obj[1], sizeof (obj[0]))
    {
    // Do stuff.
    }
```

Comment: You are seriously suggesting `memcmp` to a beginner who is already on the wrong track with all the pointer nonsense? Wow. Refraining from downvoting only because you are the first here to mention the difference between identity and equality.

Comment: @ChristianHackl He explicitly stated that he wanted to compare 2 objects without the use of operator overloading. Every suggestion, from what I've seen, was in one way, or another - related to operator overloading. This solution didn't use operator overloading, so I thought that it was direct answer to OPs question.

Answer (score 6):

How about adding this (public) method to your class ?

```
// overloading the "==" comparison operator (no templates required in this particular case
bool operator==(const DayOfYear& otherDay) const
{
    return (month == otherDay.month) && (day == otherDay.day);
}
```

Then, you can compare like this:

```
DayOfYear day1;
DayOfYear day2;
// ...
if (day1 == day2)  // syntactically equivalent to to: if (day1.operator==(day2))
{
    // ...
}
```

**EDIT**: since you don't want to use operator overloading, you can always do it with a function/static method like this:

```
bool compareDates(const DayOfYear& day1, const DayOfYear& day2)
{
    return (day1.getMonth() == day2.getMonth()) && (day1.getDay() == day2.getDay());
}
```

Then, compare like this:

```
DayOfYear day1;
DayOfYear day2;
// ...
if (compareDates(day1, day2))
{
    // ...
}
```

Comment: @itsnotmyrealname Then, just cast if you're sure it succeeds.

Comment: @itsnotmyrealname: Why can you not use it? It's the correct solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can add friend function in your class:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class DayOfYear
{
public:
void set(int monthValue, int dayValue) {
    month = monthValue;
    day = dayValue;
}

friend bool compare(DayOfYear&d1,DayOfYear&d2) {

    return (d1.getDay() == d2.getDay()) && (d1.getMonth() == d2.getMonth());
}

int getMonth( ) { return month; }

int getDay( ) { return day; }

private:
int month;
int day;
};

int main(){

DayOfYear obj[3];
obj[0].set(1,1);
obj[1].set(1,1);
obj[2].set(1,1);


if(compare(obj[0],obj[1])){
    cout<<"Match"<<endl;
}


return 0;
}
```